# Using an unassigned variable in an if-statement (Java)

Tags: java, variables, object, if-statement

This is a pretty common problem I run into when I'm programming, and I'm a beginner so it stumps me for whatever reason. Here's my code:

```
boolean valid = false;  
        do {  
            double newPrice;  
            System.out.print("Enter new price: $");  
            newPrice = scan.nextDouble();  

            if(newPrice > 0){  
                b[bookChosen].price() = new newPrice;  
                valid = true;  
            }  
        }while(!valid);
```

The newPrice double in the if-statement cannot be found, and I know why, I just can't think of a way to be able to see if the user's input is a viable number.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `new newPrice`? Why not something like `b[bookChosen].setPrice(newPrice);`?

Comment: Any reason why you can't use `double newPrice = scan.nextDouble();`?

Comment: Do you mean `b[bookChosen].price = newPrice` or even better `b[bookChosen].setNewPrice(newPrice)` do you also need to increment `bookChosen`?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple of fundamental things wrong with your code, all centered on the line:

```
 b[bookChosen].price() = new newPrice;
```

First of all, `new newPrice` doesn't do anything and won't even compile. `new` is a keyword for creating new objects, and must be followed with an invocation of a class's constructor -- `newPrice` is not a class, nor is it an invocation of a class's constructor.

Secondly, you're attempting to assign to the invocation of an object's method. You cannot assign to an invocation of an object's method -- you can only assign to names.

What you probably meant to do is something like:

```
 b[bookChosen].setPrice(newPrice);
```

This uses a setter to set the price of the object contained at `b[bookChosen]`. Using setters to change the property of an object is an extremely common convention in Java. You probably wouldn't be having these issues if you were using an IDE, which is the only way anyone ever really writes modern Java (enter obligatory plug for https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), and you'd probably learn a whole lot.

Other than that, your code is generally fine, although I think it's a little simpler written:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter new price: $");  
    double newPrice = scan.nextDouble();  

    if (newPrice > 0) {  
       b[bookChosen].setPrice(newPrice);
       break;  // leave while True loop
    }
}
```

An alternative control flow that's not quite as natural for me, is:

```
double newPrice = 0;
while (newPrice <= 0) {
    System.out.print("Enter new price: $");  
    double newPrice = scan.nextDouble();  
}
b[bookChosen].setPrice(newPrice);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `new newPrice;`

> **new** keyword is always used to create a new object not to assign a new value (this is what i understanded from your code)

2. `b[bookChosen].price()`

> of what ever class `b` is the array of that. You are assigning a value to that at the index `bookChosen`.
>
> - If price is  you method, **then values are not assigned to methods**, values are send through parameters to method.
>     like `b[bookChosen].price(newPrice)`;
> - If price is your field of that class, then it must b public or protected if it is in the same package. then variables of class are
>     not post pended by `()`. they are assigned like `b[bookChosen].price = newPrice;`
>     but it not standard always make your bean by private fields and access then through setter getters.

```
boolean valid = false;  
        do {  

            System.out.print("Enter new price: $");  
            double newPrice = scan.nextDouble();  

            if(newPrice > 0){  
                b[bookChosen].setPrice(newPrice) ;  
                valid = true;  
            }  
        }while(!valid);
```

Best Of Luck.